# Incorrect syntax near 'JSON' - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use it in my SQL Query exactly like it's shown in the link below on MSDN. The keyword JSON does not turn blue and gives error

> Incorrect syntax near 'JSON'

What's wrong with it?

EDIT: I'm testing it  for SQL Server 2014. The query is

```
SELECT * FROM food FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: JSON support starts from Sql 2016

Comment: @abhishek what is the possible solution for this?

Comment: Upgrade. If you can't upgrade, do all JSON processing outside the database. They didn't add it as a feature to 2016 for nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FOR JSON AUTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server) is available from SQL SERVER 2016. If you are using SQL SERVER 2014 or former, then you can use the following approach:

```
SELECT '['+ STUFF((
                SELECT ',{"Col1":"' + CAST(t1.name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '",'+
                        +'"Col2":"'+CAST(t1.database_id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '"}'
                    FROM Food t1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                  ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,''
              ) + ']';
```

You can validate the output using various online tools such as [JSON LINT](https://jsonlint.com/) to make sure that the result is valid json-formatted result.

**Update:**

Here is the screenshot of the code and result:

[image]

Comment: @TanveerHussain recheck your query again. I have attached a screenshot of the query and result to my answer too

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Vahid for the query very handy. Just a quick modification if the record have '\' in their value JSON will fail so modified the query to accommodate that

```
 SELECT '['+ STUFF((
      SELECT ',{"Col1":"' + REPLACE(CAST(t1.name  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'\','\\') + '",'+
           +'"Col2":"' + REPLACE(CAST(t1.value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'\','\\') + '"}'
                FROM Food t1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,''
          ) + ']';
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON AUTO` Only use in SQL Server 2016.